# Application of Rolle's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

Suppose $q$ is a nonzero function of a real-variable such that
$$u^2q''(u)+uq'(u)=u^2q(u)+q(u)$$
for all $u$.

Assume there exist $x,y$ such that $q(x)=q(y)=0$. By Rolle's there exists $x<z<y$ such that $q'(z)=0$. Plugging $z$ into the above equation is
$$z^2q''(z)+zq'(z)=z^2q(z)+q(z)\iff z^2q''(z)=z^2q(z)+q(z).$$
And plugging $x,y$ in the equation is
$$x^2q''(x)+xq'(x)=0\land y^2q''(y)+yq'(y)=0\implies xq''(x)+q(x)=0\land yq''(y)+q(y)=0.$$
I try to deduce contradiction from above but I don't know the next step. One strategy can be to show one of three equalities is actually is strict inequality. Another one can be to pursue second derivatives in the intervals $(x,z)$ and $(z,y)$ by mean value theorem. But none of these seem to show anything important. I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: Hi Dard. Can you make it more clear what is your question? You say you seek a contradiction. Is your goal to show that such a $q$ cannot be? Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: Hi, to show such x,y cannot exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We assume that for all $u$, $q$ is continuous, second differentiable and not uniformly zero on any interval.

Assume that there exist $x,y$ such that $q(x)=q(y)=0$.

Since $q$ is continuous, second differentiable and not uniformly zero on $(x,y)$ it is either the case that there is a

1. local maximum  or a
2. local minimum point $(z,q(z))$ of $q$ on the *open* interval $(x,y)$.

In either case, $q^\prime(z)=0$, so it follows that

$$ z^2q^{\prime\prime}(z)=(z^2+1)q(z) $$

So both $q(z)$ and $q^{\prime\prime}(z)$ must have the same sign.

But if $(z,q(z))$ is a global maximum $q(z)>0$ and $q^{\prime\prime}(z)<0$ and it it is a global minimum then $q(z)<0$ and $q^{\prime\prime}(z)>0$.

This is a contradiction.

So $q$ cannot have distinct zeros unless $q$ is uniformly zero on some interval.

Comment: Thank you. I have two questions about your answer. (1) what happens if $q(z)=q''(z)=0$? (2) Why is it the case that either $(z,q(z))$ must be a global maximum or $(z,q(z))$ must be a global minimum? I don't understand this either/or since the disjuncts don't seem to be negations of each other.

Comment: @Darg I thought I had an argument for $q$ and $q^{\prime\prime}$ not both $0$ on $(x,y)$ but now I don't see it. That might need the precondition that $q$ not be uniformly zero on any interval, I'll have to look at that again since I presume that is not one of the conditions, at least you did  not state that condition. That would be needed for point ($2$) also since $q$ is continuous on the closed & bounded interval $[x,y]$ and not uniformly zero on the interval.

Comment: Yes looks like you need this additional requirement.