# Prove a twice differentiable fucntion can only have at most two zeros

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a twice differentiable and nonzero function,and $x^2 f''(x)+xf'(x)-(x^2+1)f(x)=0$.Prove function $f$ can at most have one zero.

Prove by contradiction.

Suppose function $f$ have more than one zeros, and select the most near two zeros $a$ and $b$. Also, $0<a<b$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Since a and b are nearest two zeros, then all functions values in interval [a,b] should have the same sign. (Otherwise if there exists $f(c)<0$,$f(d)>0$, then by IVT, there exists another zero between [c,d].This is a contracition with a and b are nearest zero points.)

Since $f$ is differentiable on [a,b] and $f(a)=f(b)=0$, there exists a value $x_0\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x_0)=0 $. Then take this into $x^2 f''(x)+xf'(x)-(x^2+1)f(x)=0$

Getting $f''(x_0)=\frac{({x_0}^2+1)f(x_0)}{{x_{0}}^2}$. Since ${x_0}^2+1$ and ${x_{0}}^2$ are positive, the sign of $f''$ is controlled by $f(x_0)$ only. Suppose $f(x_0)>0$，plus all $f(x)$ have the same sign on interval [a,b]. Then the graph of $f$ on [a,b] should be like [image]

However, in point $x_1$, plugging it into the equation $x^2 f''(x)+xf'(x)-(x^2+1)f(x)=0$ can also get $f''(x_1)=\frac{({x_1}^2+1)f(x_1)}{{x_{1}}^2}$, but this equation can't be correct, since $f''(x_1)<0$ but $f(x_1)>0$. Similarly for $x=x_2$ and $f(x_0)<0$

I have two questions.

The first is that whether my proof contains some correct ideas. I think the last part of using a picture to illustrate can't be formal proof and I just give not the general case by using the picture, but I wonder whether this is a correct idea.

The second one is that is there another way of using MVT or Rolle's theorem to prove this. When the first time I met this question, the only thing I can know is that since $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f$ is differentiable then apply Rolle's theorem to claim there exists a $x_0$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$ and plug this into the previous equation. Then nothing I can do.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322215/application-of-rolles) was asked earlier today

Comment: Is there an error in the assumptions? Because you say $f$ is "a twice differentiable and nonzero function" and then say you are to prove $f$ can have at most one zero. But you have already *assumed* it is nonzero.